# Symfony, get GET parameters in route method

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

Have a problem.

There is my route method:

```
book_list:
  url:      /api/books.:sf_format
  class:    sfDoctrineRoute
  options:  { model: Book, type: list, method: getActiveWithAuthor }
  param:    { module: book, action: list, sf_format: json }
  requirements:
    sf_format: (?:json|html)
```

code in action is simple:

```
public function executeList(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->books = $this->getRoute()->getObjects();
}
```

And custom method for getting the Books

```
public function getActiveWithAuthor(array $parameters) {
    // crit is easy to find in logs.
    sfContext::getInstance()->getLogger()->crit(var_export($parameters, true));
    return BookQuery::create()
    ->addSelf()
    ->addAuthor()
    ->execute();
}
```

The problem is, that I would like to filter books by optional parammeter "date_from", which could be in url, e.g. /api/books?date_from=2011-02-18

But in log I could see only "sf_format => html" (or json)
What should I use for getting the optional parrameter "date_from"?

Comment: use var_export($array, ture) instead of that foreach hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function executeList(sfWebRequest $request) 
{
  $this->books = Doctrine::getTable('Book')-> getActiveWithAuthor($request->getParameter('date'));
}

//BookTable.class.php
public function getActiveWithAuthor($date) 
{
  $q = $this->createQuery('b')
    ->leftJoin('b.Author')
    ->where('b.date > ?', $date);

  return $q->execute();  
}
```

Comment: That what I exactly did. But I'd like to use just
$this->books = $this->getRoute()->getObjects();

Comment: As I see, in my case, I can't use $parameters in route method. Parameters must be defined in the url, as /:slug/:date_from/:id or something.
And I gave up and use that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your parameter from the request object:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameter('date_from');
```

**UPDATE**
Better solution, without sfContext::getInstance() :

```
class myCustomRoute extends sfDoctrineRoute
{
  public function getRealVariables()
  {
    return array_merge('date_from', parent::getRealVariables());
  }
}
```

Specify the use of this class in routing.yml and you may use this parameter directly in your method.

Comment: Oh, come on! Do you really need a singleton here?

Comment: @Dziamid: the goal is to use the method option of the route.

Comment: @Dziamid: I read [this article](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/) too, but the OP is asking for something difficult to achieve without it. If you can do it, then propose your solution, but the one you've proposed so far uses the action, not the route. I guess this might be possible by using a custom route though.

Comment: using the sfContext::getInstance() in model - bad practice, because it doesn't work for tests.

Comment: @maectpo: I posted a link in my previous comment, read it, you'll see that it works, but requires many things to work. I agree, it is bad practice, but "you'd like to use just $this->books = $this->getRoute()->getObjects();". But have a look at the sfObjectRoute class.

Comment: If you redefine your own route, override the `getRealVariables()` method, you may be able to pass date_from as a parameter for your method. I'm gonna post an update on this

Comment: It works, but in another way. 
If I specify :date_from in url section in routing, e.g.
url:      /api/books.:sf_format/:date_from
it will be in the $parameters, even without the myCustomRoute.

But if date_from is just a GET parameter (url?date_from=2011-02-18) it won't work.

Comment: @maectpo: great! I wasn't aware of that, but it feels quite logic